# Compact formula for $\sum_k k!$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, factorial

Is there any compact formula for:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n k!$$

I've tried to find it using one method for summation, but I was able to receive only compact formula for $\sum_k k! \cdot k = (n+1)!-1$

I've typed it into wolfram, but [answer is also pretty complicated](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+k%21%2C+k%3D0...n).

Comment: I want to find compact formula for $\sum_{k=0}^n (k^2+1)k!$, and I have simplified everything besides part $\sum_k k!$

Comment: Here's a direction: we have that $(k+1)^2 = k^2 + 2k + 1$, so that $(k+1)^2 k! = (k+1) \cdot (k+1)!$. You know a form for the sum of $k \cdot k!$, so do you see how to get a form for $(k^2 + 1) k!$?

Comment: $(k+1)^2-2k=k^2+1$.

Comment: OK guys, I've solved this task. Thank you all for your hints! Because questions is connected with $\sum_k k!$ I accepted this answer that refers to that sum.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may prefer to deal with the following integral representation

> $$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}k! = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \Gamma(k+1)= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{k}e^{-x}dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}e^{-x}dx , $$

where $\Gamma(s)$ is the gamma function.

Comment: I hereby annoit Mhenni as king of the Gamma functions! (+1)

Comment: @RonGordon: Thanks for the comment. I really appreciate it. On this website, we are really learning from each other. Thanks for everyone who is contributing and working on this website.

Answer (score 6):

This is [A003422](https://oeis.org/A003422); the only more or less closed form expression given there is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k!=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}e^{-x}dx\;.$$

Comment: But note also the e.g.f.: $(Ei(1)-Ei(1-x)) e^{x-1}$.  That is, 
$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i!$ is $n!$ times the coefficient of $x^n$ in the Taylor series of that function.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n (k^2+1)k!  &=  \sum_{k=0}^n [(k+1)^2-2k]k!  \\  &= 
 \sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)(k+1)!  -\sum_{k=0}^n 2k \cdot k!  \\  &=  \bigl((n+2)!+1\bigr) -2 \bigl((n+1)!+1\bigr)  \\  &=  n(n+1)! -1
\end{align}

Comment: You forgot to multiply 2 in the third formula.

Comment: I fixed it.. ty.

Comment: Note that this (through whatever OP did to get $\sum k^2 k!$) would give a nice formula for $\sum k!$, to be reported at OEIS (and make this site _world_ famous ;-)...

Comment: Good point ,OP must have made a mistake there--- otherwise we would have contacted The On-line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: Yes, that's right I've made a mistake in my calculation. Well, unfortunately, we did not discover a new formula for $\sum k!$ :)