# What is the value of $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k!$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, summation, factorial

What is the sum of all the factorials starting from 1 to n? Is there any generalized formula for such summation?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A003422 has some information about the related sum which starts from 0 instead of 1. There is almost certainly not a nice formula (unless you would consider $\sum_1^n k!$ to already be a nice formula).

Comment: See also http://oeis.org/A007489.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350514/compact-formula-for-sum-k-k).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one of the cases where appears the [subfactorial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k!=-1-!1-(-1)^n(n+1)!\times !(-2-n)$$ and,as you will notice in the Wikipedia page, $$!m = \left[ \frac{m!}{e} \right]  = \left\lfloor\frac{m!}{e}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor, \quad m\geq 1$$ or, more generally $$!m=\frac{\Gamma (m+1,-1)}{e}$$ where appears the incomplete gamma function ([see here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subfactorial.html)).

Comment: +1. Nice answer. Note a 'minor typo': Wi$\color{#f00}{\large\mathrm{l}}$ipedia.